# Factorial not working (edited post)

Tags: java

Why is the factorial code not working please advise...
Is there something wrong with the variables or just the logic? What should I change? I really appreciate your time. Thanks a lot!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class factorial{
public static void main(String args[])
{


  System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate its factorial");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input = sc.nextLine();
  int x = Integer.parseInt(input);

  try { 
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nFE) {
        System.out.println("Not an Integer");
    }
    }
      int fact(int x)
        {
          int result;

           if(x==1)
             return 1;

           result = fact(x-1) * x;
           int number = result;
        System.out.println(fact(number));
           return result;



        }

    }
```

### Thanks for your help...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.out.println(fact(number));